# I need a simple incrementation over time function

Tags: android, time, timer, increment

I want to do a cookie clicker like app and i need a simple incrementation over time function.
But i would only want the int to start increasing once i have pressed a button.
I tried this but does not work properly.

```
 int delay = 5000; 
 int period = 1000; 
 int count = 0;
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {


            count++;
            score.setText(String.valueOf(count));


        }
    }, delay, period);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason its not working is because `run()` is running on separate Thread, not on UIThread. You need to run `setText` in UIThread. see the code below

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            count++;
                            score.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, delay, period);
```